# How to prevent Access 2007 from going to design tab when opening forms in design view

Tags: xml, ms-access, tabs, ms-access-2007, ribbon

So I have created a custom tab for Access 2007 via XML and I would like Access to not move off of this tab unless the user chooses to. The biggest problem is when I open a form in design view Access will automatically switch to it's own design tab instead of staying on my tab that has all the tools I use already there. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent this automatic switching tabs or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to capture the Form Close event, which fires when changing to Design View, and then sending the necessary keystrokes to activate your custom Ribbon tab. Hit Alt to see what the keytip of your particular ribbon tab is, or set a custom keytip in the XML:

```
  <tab id="tabExample" label="Test" keytip="XYZ" >
```

My tab (I didn't bother with XML for this) was assigned Y2:

[image]

```
Private Sub Form_Close(Cancel As Integer)

    SendKeys "%(Y2)", False
    SendKeys "{esc}", True
    SendKeys "{esc}", True

End Sub
```

Obviously this will fire whenever you close the form as well as switching to Design View (although from your requirements it sounds like this may be acceptable). [It is, however, possible to check what view a form is in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224167(v=office.11).aspx), although I'm not sure how one would go about putting this into the code we have. Checking what state the form is in during the Form Close event would still return with Form View (ie. open) not Design View.